# Which font is used in QML application if the symbols are not supported by the chosen font?

Tags: fonts, localization, qml, asianfonts

In our QML application, we use a custom font for UI. The same font is used to render a PDF report document.

When adding the new translations (Russian, Chinese, Japanese, Korean), we noticed the following:

1. Our custom font doesn't have symbols for new languages but all the UI still works.
2. PDF doesn't work unless you explicitly set the font of the document to something that surely contains symbols (e.g. 'Arial Unicode MS' for Korean)

I would like to better understand the logic behind, so here are 2 questions:

1. How does QML decide, which font to fall back to, in case the requested font doesn't contain the necessary symbols? As I mentioned, UI works for all the fonts.
2. Is there some documentation from Qt about how do deal with such situations (in total we have about 10 languages).